# Regex include line breaks

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have the following xml file

```
<p style="1">
A
</p>
<div xml:lang="unknown">
<p style="3">
B
C
</div>
<div xml:lang="English">
<p style="5">
D
</p>
<p style="1">
Picture number 3?
</p>
```

and I just want to get the text between `<div xml:lang="unknown">` and `</div>`.
So I've tried this code :

```
import os, re

html = open("2.xml", "r")
text = html.read()
lon = re.compile(r'<div xml:lang="unknown">\n(.+)\n</div>', re.MULTILINE)
lon = lon.search(text).group(1)
print lon
```

but It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Parsing XML with regex is the wrong approach to take. Use a parser, and the pain is much less!

Comment: Can you suggest me an xml parser ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Comment: I'm gonna try, thank you.

Comment: You can split the text at the <div>, creating a list of <div>s to iterate over and apply your regex to the list item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Don't parse XML with regex. It just doesn't work. Use an [XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python).

2) If you do use regex for this, you don't want [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), which controls how `^` and `$` work in a multiple-line string. You want [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), which controls whether `.` matches `\n` or not.

3) You probably also want your pattern to return the shortest possible match, using the [non-greedy `+?` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

```
lon = re.compile(r'<div xml:lang="unknown">\n(.+?)\n</div>', re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse a piece of block code like this , when you in a block and set a flag True, and when you out and set the flag False and break out.

```
def get_infobox(self):
    """returns Infobox wikitext from text blob
    learning form https://github.com/siznax/wptools/blob/master/wp_infobox.py
    """
    if self._rawtext:
        text = self._rawtext
    else:
        text = self.get_rawtext()
    output = []
    region = False
    braces = 0
    lines = text.split("\n")
    if len(lines) < 3:
        raise RuntimeError("too few lines!")

    for line in lines:
        match = re.search(r'(?im){{[^{]*box$', line)
        braces += len(re.findall(r'{{', line))
        braces -= len(re.findall(r'}}', line))
        if match:
            region = True
        if region:
            output.append(line.lstrip())
            if braces <= 0:
                region = False
                break
    self._infobox = "\n".join(output)
    assert self._infobox
    return self._infobox
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting on the div and just matching on the list item.  This works well for regex's on large data as well.

```
import re

html = """<p style="1">
A
</p>
<div xml:lang="unknown">
<p style="3">
B
C
</div>
<div xml:lang="English">
<p style="5">
D
</p>
<p style="1">
Picture number 3?
</p>
"""

for div in html.split('<div'):
 m = re.search(r'xml:lang="unknown">.+(<p[^<]+)', div, re.DOTALL)
 if m:
   print m.group(1)
```